# Removing coordinates from a dataarray that has been converted to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, python-xarray

I have a dataarray that contains a list of values over lat,lon points across the globe. I want to supply a list of lat,lon values for specific cities and apply the values at those lat,lon points to create a dataframe. To accomplish this, I do the code below.

```
df1=pd.read_csv('E:/Riskpulse_HD/TroPYcal/GenscapePortList.csv')

lats=df1['Latitude']
lons=df1['Longitude']

count_city=[]
for idx,(lon,lat) in enumerate(zip(lons,lats)):
    val = grid.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest')
    count_city.append(val)

print(np.shape(count_city))
```

The print that comes out looks like this:

```
[<xarray.DataArray ()>
 array(0.)
 Coordinates:
     lat      float64 40.0
     lon      float64 28.0,
 <xarray.DataArray ()>
 array(0.)
 Coordinates:
     lat      float64 40.0
     lon      float64 28.0,
 <xarray.DataArray ()>
 array(0.)
 Coordinates:
     lat      float64 42.0
     lon      float64 28.0,
```

So this still looks like a dataarray, but when doing a `type()` command it is a list. How can I go about simply stripping the coordinates part of this list?

When creating the dataframe, it looks like this:

```
df1['Counts']= count_city
df1.head()

Latitude    Longitude   Port Name   Counts
0   39.871112   20.003421   Sarande <xarray.DataArray ()>\narray(0.)\nCoordinates:...
1   40.450605   19.483051   Vlora   <xarray.DataArray ()>\narray(0.)\nCoordinates:...
2   41.810046   19.584720   Shengjin    <xarray.DataArray ()>\narray(0.)\nCoordinates:...
3   41.308849   19.454677   Durres  <xarray.DataArray ()>\narray(0.)\nCoordinates:...
4   35.819101   -0.247319   Bettioua    <xarray.DataArray ()>\narray(0.)\nCoordinates:...
```

I just want all of the values associated with the coordinates. I am familiar with how to do this when the type is a dataarray, but unsure with a list.

Comment: can you convert the dataarray to a list? `list(<dataarray>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the code is indeed a list, but a list of `DataArray` objects. From the [xarray docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-don-t-aggregations-return-python-scalars):

> xarray tries hard to be self-consistent: operations on a `DataArray` (resp. `Dataset`) return another `DataArray` (resp. `Dataset`) object. In particular, operations returning scalar values (e.g. indexing or aggregations like mean or sum applied to all axes) will also return xarray objects.

To get a numpy array instead, you have to add [`.values`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/howdoi.html?highlight=dataarray.values) (could also be `.data` if working with Dask arrays and wanted to keep the underlying data structure).

```
val = grid.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest')
```